# Meaning of "*" in a regular expression for grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm having trouble finding what the `*` does in the grep command. I'm following this example:

```
ian@attic4:~/lpi103-7$ grep "p*" text1
1 apple
2 pear
3 banana
```

Why does `banana` appear if `p*` is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` symbol means "0 or more times", so the `p` character does not need to be in the line for it to be matched. If you want the `p` character to appear at least one time, use `+` instead.

Comment: Notice that that requires `grep -E`, or (if the grep version supports it; GNU grep does) it has to be escaped: `\+`.

Comment: Is + the only one that has to be escaped?

Comment: By the way, simple grep without -E and without + , just `grep "p"` will also exclude banana and will print entries with at least one p in line / entry.